# putting two different html page in a tab system

Tags: html, tabs

I emplemented two html pages separately. how can put them in the same page (tabs system). ALl the example found on the net are more about simple content tabs (text or so..)
thanks

Comment: Can you use some Javascript ? Because using tabs implies that you handle actions onclick on a button, and this is very easy with Javascript and nearly impossible in pure HTML/CSS

Comment: can I have an example of using javascript please!

Comment: There are thousands of Javascript opensource codes available on Internet, just search a little bit

Comment: can u specify the key word(s) to look for.. since "tabs" is all that can accure to my mind and apparently it's not the right term to look for. thank you

Comment: You are not making efforts... I typed "Javascript HTML tabs" and the first link is exactly what you are searching for..

Comment: it's not about maing effort.. i just typed "Javascript HTML tabs" and most of the results are pages that i counselled but none is giving me an example of what I'm looking for!

Comment: <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp">This</a> is the first result on Google : a complete tutorial on How to create Tabs in Javascript for HTML

Answer (score 0):

Call the files using iframe in tab content just keep your markup in html files and don't put any styles or script in that file.

Comment: iframe are not such a good idea since the browser is loading another page for each iframe, which can be pretty expensive in terms of loading time for people without a huge internet connexion

Comment: HTML page are of same site then there would be no loading issue and no further css request for it. If they are third party then there would be loading issue.

Comment: I agree that times will be shorter since there is no network connexion. However, the browser will still be looking for much more data from different pages, read it and apply CSS to it, so there will likely be longer loading times.

Comment: I worked a lot earlier using this approach never felt something like this. Although thanks for advice might be it didn't worked for you properly

Answer (score 0):

How about using HTML includes? 
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.js"></script>

<body>

<div w3-include-html="<path to html file goes here>"></div> 

<script>
w3.includeHTML();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

working example here:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_html_include_1

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers! but I'm looking more for showing the content of the page. I'm already using frames in each page so putting it in frame is not the best solution for my case.

I think I found my answer in the load() function of jquery to load dynamically a page! here's an example: http://www.jquery-tutorial.net/ajax/the-load-method/
where you can simply add the link of the page.

http://www.jquery-tutorial.net/ajax/the-load-method/
this library is not bad too but I'm going for a tab system and a jquery load for each tab!